# Server-side javascript with node (and Django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, node.js

I have node installed on my server. I want to execute a JavaScript file that basically takes some information from a Django model. How could I pass JSON and large textarea variables into my node script from inside Django?

```
class Page(models.Model):                
    html    = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)                
    less    = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    context = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)

    def render(self):
        # pass context (converted to JSON), less and html to node script and compile.
        # How to do this?
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see the keywords less and html. What are you expecting node to do exactly?

Comment: @travis I just used that as a quick example that came to mind. In this example, I wanted to compile a less template server-side and render it with the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I was able to do this:

```
import subprocess
...
command_list = ['node', 'static/js/node_script.js']

try:
  output = subprocess.check_output(command_list)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
  output = "Error in command_list."
```